# Alerting when heartbeat not received

Tags: azure-application-insights

I've got an Application Insights log being written to by a Windows Service.  Is it possible to set an alert for inactivity; for instance "If not been written to in the last 15 minutes, activate an alert"?

Comment: This functionality has recently been added to the Application Insights SDK.  And there is now a metric alert for it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there isn't such an option out of the box.
What I would recommend doing is firing your custom metric for Keep Alive with a value of 1 every so-and-so minutes, and define a custom alert (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-alerts)) on it in case the value drops below some threshold.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in Application Insights Heartbeat metrics.

Q&A: https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Home/blob/master/heartbeat/heartbeat-q-and-a.md

Spec: https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Home/blob/master/heartbeat/heartbeat-specification.md

Comment: The links no longer work. Can you add some additional info to understand how heartbeat work? or perhaps look for this in old versiong in github repo?